# Surround strings in a list with a certain character

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list consisting of strings and I need to surround each of the strings with asterisks. With the input:

```
def addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"])
```

The output should be:

```
["*abc*", "*ded*"]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
for x in strs:
   x = "*" + x + "*"
```

However, the output is unchanged:

```
["abc", "ded"]
```

Comment: "can't get it to work" - can you describe what happens?

Comment: Python strings are immutable, that's why your solution is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a local variable, so changing it is meaningless once it goes out of scope. You could, e.g., return the modified list and assign it somewhere:

```
def addAsterisks(l)
    return ['*' + x + '*' for x in l]

myList = addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use, also, `str.format()`:

```
def addAsterisks(a):
    # Or:
    # return ["*%s*" %k for k in a]
    return ["*{}*".format(k) for k in a]

print(addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"]))
>>> ['*abc*', '*ded*
```

Comment: Or: `return [f'*{k}*' for k in a]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the list to reflect changes in your list. I used inline function for compact code.

**Code**

```
['*'+ i + "*" for picture in pictures]
```

**input**

```
["abc", "def"]
```

**Output**

```
["*abc*", "*def*"]
```

Comment: Note that what you have provided it not a function, and so your claim about input is false. It would be correct to say that with the given value of `pictures`, the output is the provided.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the the array and return to where you want to use. Modifying a temp variable (x) wont work since u will loose it once you are out of scope.

```
def addAsterisks(string_list):
  return ['*' + x + '*' for x in string_list]

print addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"])
```

This will output:

```
['*abc*', '*ded*']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to a temporary variable `x`, which does not change the actual list. Try instead

```
return ["*" + x + "*" for x in picture]
```

or, if you want a loop:

```
for i,x in enumerate(picture):
    picture[i] = "*" + x + "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
In [22]: def addAsterisks(s):
    ...:     newarr = []
    ...:     for i in s:
    ...:         newstr = "*" + str(i) + "*"
    ...:         newarr.append(newstr)
    ...:     print(newarr)
    ...:     

In [23]: addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"])
['*abc*', '*ded*']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Pythonic way of tackling this question:

```
A = [ "*"+a+"*" for a in picture ]
```

Hint: Read about *list comprehension* in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late at the party.

Other solutions are better for the specific use case, but this might help someone else (it is a totally different approach from other answers).

If you are **really** sure about the length of each string to be exactly three, you can do the following:

```
def addAsterisks(items):
    return [ f'{value:*^5}' for value in items ]

addAsterisks(["abc","def"])
```

Please note that if you change 5 to 7 you will surrond each string with 2 asterisks